# Minimum sum after doing many operations

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

We are given a list of numbers A. In this list if we perform one operation then the following things we can do:

1)select any subpart of the list. let say from L to R.
2) Let X be the xor of all the numbers of that sub part.
3) and now we can either replace A[L] with X or A[R] with X.

We can perform this operation any number of times.

So that we can a minimum sum of that list.

We have to find minimum sum after doing any number of time operations

example:

list: 1,2,3

sub part from [1,3] . Xor = 0
so the new list is 1,2,0
minimum sum = 3

I could not get how to start it.
Please can someone help me in this

Comment: You described a setup of what is happening but what exactly is the problem? you want to find sum? number of operations required ?

Comment: @SagarM I have to find minimum sum.